# How can I check what version of laravel-query-builder am I using?

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

[An important security release for laravel-query-builder was launched](https://murze.be/an-important-security-release-for-laravel-query-builder). 
Since I use it in my project, I want to check what version I am using. But I couldn't find it. I already searched in my composer.json file. Laravel version that is being used is `"laravel/framework": "5.8.*"`.

Where is it located?

Comment: The blog states that it is about a third party package" https://github.com/spatie/laravel-query-builder . Check for that package in your composer.lock file and decide whether to update or not.

Comment: @Loek There's no package with this name in my composer.lock.  I also searching for substrings like query, builder and laravel to see all cases, but nothing as found. Any suggestion?

Comment: @B.Almeida Sounds like you're not using the package. It's not a standard part of a Laravel installation - you'd have to have deliberately installed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if this package is installed in your installation, type in your terminal:

```
composer show
```

It will show all your installed packages.

If you not installed this package with the command:

```
composer require spatie/laravel-query-builder
```

That package will not exist in your Laravel folder, because it's not a default package. And you do not have to worry.

Answer (score 0):

Execute `composer info | grep laravel-query-builder` on your project root folder.

That will give you your installed version of the package, if the output is empty you don't have it installed.